# How can I fix 404 page while trying to authenticate user with omniauth-github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

Everytime I click the "Sign in with Github" button, I get a Page not found. When I try `http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/github/callback`
I get an error called OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError which says "csrf_detected | CSRF detected" . Here is my code:

initializers/omniauth.rb:

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :github, ENV['GITHUB_ID'], ENV['GITHUB_SECRET'],
        :scope => 'user,public_repo', 
        :redirect_uri => ENV['http://127.0.0.1:3000']
end
```

routes.rb:

```
root 'users#new'
  get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create'
  get '/signout' => 'sessions#destroy', as: :signout
end
```

views/users/new.html.erb:

```
<% if current_user %>
<h1> Welcome: </h1>
<h2><%= link_to 'Sign out', signout_path %></h2>
<% else %>
<h2><%= link_to 'Sign in with Github', "/auth/github" %></h2>
<% end %>
```

sessions_controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.where(:provider => auth['provider'], :uid => auth['uid'].to_s).first || User.from_omniauth(auth)
    reset_session
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
  end

    def destroy
        session[:user_id] = nil
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'Signed out!'
    end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => "Authentication error: #{params[:message].humanize}"
  end
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
       # where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap 
       create! do |user|
       user.provider = auth.provider
       user.uid = auth.uid
       user.name = auth.info.name
       user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
       user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
       user.save!
     end
   end
end
```

application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user

private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end 
end
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this error by adding `scope: 'user:email'` to the end of the `provider` statement in the OmniAuth initializer file.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :github, ENV['GITHUB_KEY'], ENV['GITHUB_SECRET'], scope: 'user:email'
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Error 404 means "File or Directory not found". In other words, the server received and understood your request, and would have been quite willing to fulfil the request, but the data that you asked for doesn't exist.

Comment: Could you please let me know how I can attempt to fix it?

Comment: The question is not about the meaning of 404 but about fixing the 404 issue when using omniauth-github. For which I would also like to hear a solution.